# How do I delete a SQLite DB on my Android Emulator?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator

I assume that this is the solution to the problem. The error I keep getting says in a raw query I pass that a certain table does not exist. I have since changed the name of this class and every instance of it in the code, but it only returns an error on one line only. Eclipse still thinks it is using the old code. I do not know what to think other than it is using the old database table names. Any help on this would be appreciated.

I have tried the suggestions given, but it still refers to old code. I am not using the table name classes. I am using the table name class in my statements...

09-27 13:02:15.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7530): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gpa.calc/gpa.calc.GPACalculator}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: classes: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT year, COUNT(*) FROM classes

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse Goto Menu Windows->Show View->Other...->
Under Android, Pick File Explorer,
on the console, expand data, expand data again. expand your application in context, select the db file on this console's top right corner you ll find a red - symbol.

that should do it.

Comment: I followed your instructions and I have a blank File Explorer tab even after expanding the files.

Comment: The file explorer tab should usually have 3 folders data, sdcard and system. ????

Comment: Did you try to do it while emulator is running?

Answer (score 0):

The DB of the application you are developing should be able to be cleared by going to Settings->Applications->Your Application->Clear Data. Then you should have no DB for your corresponding application anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1) run ddms. 
2) Choose adv 
3) File explorer 
4) data/data/yourapp/database 
5) select and delete

Answer (score 0):

I periodically delete and create a new AVD to clear out code that is still hanging around. Wiping user data only clears the non-public data. Also, some 'crashes' seem to leave the emulator in a state that doesn't allow clean reloads.

I also 'pull' data off of the emulator to an external file when I want to checkpoint database updates. If things go south, I can create a new AVD and SD image. Then push the external database to the new SD image.

It seems that emulators don't always reinit cleanly after they've been used a few times.

Note: Snapshots do not restore 'public' data on an SD card disk image.